# Serial Ethernet Board for PIC16F887

Tags: microcontroller, microc

I have microcontroller pic16f887 and serial ethernet board. When start browser i have problem - the message is this site can't be reached and i can show the content in browser. What may be the problem????  I use HTTPServerExample
http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/communication/serial-ethernet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the IP address configured correct? Wireshark is a very nice tool you can run on your PC to track the TCP/IP traffic and try to detect what goes wrong.